# ipad rotation problem in a view based app using uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am creating an app for ipad for the first time.
i have created a view based app and in appdelegate i have added uinavigationcontroller.
in myappviewController (myapp is project name) screen is rotating. Then i have created a new file(right click class folder->Add->new file->ios cocoa touch class->UIViewController subclass.
now i am pushing this view using

```
    [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:secondview animated:YES];
```

now this view is not rotating.
shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation is returning YES in both files.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: now both views are not rotating, but when i tried [self presentModalViewController:t animated:YES]; 2nd view loaded with landscape orientation

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question, thought you wanted to rotate your view to landscape mode ;p
Did you check 'Targeted for iPad' when you created your second view?